# What are the guidelines for avoiding namespace and type name conflicts in C#?

Tags: c#, namespaces

Clean code should use short, meaningful names for entities. Thus, given an application that deals with, say, robots, I would want to have a class library project `Robot` with namespace `Robot` that has a class `Robot`. Lets assume that there is only a single robot object, like e.g. the code of [Hubot](https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/master/src/robot.js).

However, [naming a class name the same as its namespace is an extremely bad idea in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx).

What are the guidelines for avoiding namespace and type name conflicts?

Specifically, considering the case above, how should I name the namespace if I want to keep the class name `Robot`?

Comment: Name the namespace `Robots`. See also: `System.Collections` and many other examples in the BCL.

Comment: (Also, voting to close because this is guaranteed to be an opinion poll. Names are arbitrary, pick one that makes sense to you and is valid.)

Comment: @millimoose, I disagree that this an opinion poll. I would like to gather realistic, justifiable conventions that are based on sound reasoning.

Comment: Read the Framework Design Guidelines.

Comment: @mrts What is the metric by which you would judge the validity of an answer.  Beyond just "compiles" and "doesn't compile" how do you expect to judge whether a particular convention is preferable or not?  With clear criteria, it really does boil down to personal opinion without any facts/references/expertise/etc.

Comment: Using a plural for the namespace name would unfortunately be conceptually misleading in this case as there is only a single robot that we create - https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/master/src/robot.coffee demonstrates the concept well.

Comment: However, I will accept `Robots` as an answer if nothing more elegant shows up as (1) it corresponds to the Framework Design Guidelines and (2) it keeps the namespace name short and meaningful.

Comment: @mrts What you want to gather and what kind of answers your question, **as stated**, will attract are two different things. Naming conventions are inherently *arbitrary*, you carry the burden of responsibility to not make them so by imposing constraints an answer should satisfy. I'm objecting to the fact that there's no reason why anyone shouldn't answer with "I like this one best", and there's no reason why you'd answer an answer for other reasons than "I like this one best". (Read "there's no reason" as "you gave no reason".)

Comment: @millimoose, whatever. I asked for guidelines and Eric's answer is a concrete guideline that I'm able to apply in the future. However, I see your point and respect your freedom to regard the question as arbitrary and close it as non-constructive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The guidelines are very clear: namespaces outside of `System` should be `Company.Technology`. This allows both clear disambiguation and makes it easier for users to discover what namespaces are associated with what technologies.  Remember, the primary purpose of a namespace is not collision avoidance, but rather developer productivity.

Guidelines are here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618(v=vs.71).aspx

Your namespace should be something like:

```
namespace MrtsCorp.Robotics 
{
  public sealed class Robot 
  {
     ...
```

If you want to look at a reasonable model for such a namespace, try these:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd159952.aspx

I am not thrilled with namespaces with names like `Ccr`, which are clear only to domain experts, but `Microsoft.Robotics.Simulation` is nicely descriptive.

Comment: Thank you! That is going to the direction I was looking for. I had a similar vague feeling, but was unable to pinpoint that the namespace should name the general technology domain. I will accept this as an answer unless anything even better shows up.

Comment: The guideline is not only a good thing. After a couple of mergers and acquisitions we ended up with 4 different top level namespaces within the company. Not in the same project of course but common utilities is not easy to discover. Resharper helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest workaround, if you really can't come up with anything, is to call the namespace `Robots`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Framework Design Guidelines on Names of Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx) a namespace should be in the following format:

```
<Company>.(<Product>|<Technology>)[.<Feature>][.<Subnamespace>]
```

so since the "company" here is the open source project team for `Hubot` and really none of the other categories apply here then for your example it would be something like:

```
namespace HubotDev.Hubot
{
    public sealed class Robot
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

And the useage would be

```
Hubot.Robot robot = //...;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what is in the namespace. The namespace has to describe what's inside of it. If you have a bunch of robots class then naming it Robots is a good idea. If you have a robot and a parts of robot then it could be names RobotEntities, RobotParts, Machine ...

Maybe your Robot class isn't named properly, maybe it's a BaseRobot, or EnemyRobot, ...

Answer (score -2):

And another out of many possible ideas is to use lower case for namespace.

It's not common, however sometimes such names are used for namespaces. Even though it's not conforming to the naming guidelines, the whole scenario isn't (it doesn't match the [`CompanyName.TechnologyName[.Feature][.Design]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) standard).